# Very easy question regarding the triangle inequality

Tags: real-analysis

This question may be far too easy for this site but I always seem to get stuck when it comes to the triangle inequality.

For example, I am trying to prove that differentiability implies Lipschitz continuity. Ok, I don't really have a hard time with this except for the step when using the triangle inequality.

Let $| x -x_0| < \epsilon$. Suppose $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$. Then

$ |f(x)-f(x_0)-f'(x_0)(x-x_0) | < | x- x_0|$

The next step is where I am not sure how the triangle inequality allows this,

$|f(x)-f(x_0)| \le |f'(x_0)(x-x_0)|+|x-x_0|$

Why am I allowed to add the $|f'(x_0)(x-x_0)|$ to the right hand side??

Sorry that this question is most likely trivial but I always get stuck with this operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the [reverse triangle inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality) is used in your case: $| \ |a|-|b|\ | \leq |a-b|$ for any real numbers $a,b$.

Applying this in the setting of your problem:

$$ |f(x)-f(x_0)|-|f'(x_0)(x-x_0)| \leq \left| |f(x)-f(x_0)|-|f'(x_0)(x-x_0)| \right| \\ \leq |f(x_0)+f(x)-f'(x_0)(x-x_0)| \leq |x-x_0|$$

add $|f'(x_0)(x-x_0)|$ on both sides to recover the expression you want.

Answer (score 0):

The triangle inequality gives you $|f(x)-f(x_0)|-|f'(x_0)(x-x_0) | \le |f(x)-f(x_0)-f'(x_0)(x-x_0) |$ so you have $|f(x)-f(x_0)|-|f'(x_0)(x-x_0) |\le |f(x)-f(x_0)-f'(x_0)(x-x_0) | < | x- x_0|\\|f(x)-f(x_0)|\le|f'(x_0)(x-x_0) |+ | x- x_0|$